# best way to represent large symbols in exponents

Tags: math-mode

a paper I'm writing uses the mathematical term `$2^{\sum |f_e|}$`, which compiles to look horribly similar to `$2 \sum |f_e|$`.

is there any latex wizardry that will let me express large exponents such that they are more clearly exponents?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: How about `$\prod 2^{|f_e|}$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least three possible solutions:

1. Raise the exponent higher with a `\raisebox`;
2. Make the exponent smaller by setting it to `\scriptscriptstyle` (assuming the whole `2^{\sum |f_e|}` is not already in `\scriptstyle`);
3. Use the exponential function instead of a superscript.

The first two options can also be combined. Here's an example comparing all of these.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\setlist[description]{
    align=right,
    font=\normalfont,
    labelsep=5mm,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[No exponent]
        \(2 \sum \abs{f_e}\)
    \item[Default]
        \(2^{\sum \abs{f_e}}\)
    \item[Raised exponent]
        \(2^{\raisebox{1mm}{\(\scriptstyle\sum \abs{f_e}\)}}\)
    \item[Smaller exponent]
        \(2^{\scriptscriptstyle\sum \abs{f_e}}\)
    \item[Raised smaller exponent]
        \(2^{\raisebox{1mm}{\(\scriptscriptstyle\sum \abs{f_e}\)}}\)
    \item[With exponential function]
        \(\exp\bigl( \log 2 \sum \abs{f_e} \bigr)\)
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good solution. My guess No.3 would have been Paul Halmos preference and in text he would have written 2 raised to the power of ... He was a great advocate of "choose your notation carefully"!

Comment: I like this a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it look different than the default consider using an `underbrace` or better use [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\def\tsum#1{\underbrace{#1}}

Inline as requested $2^{\tsum{|f_e|}}$,
and as display with uparrow$(\uparrow)$ notation. 
$$
  \begin{matrix}
   a\uparrow b = H_3(a,b) = a^b = & \underbrace{a\times a\times\dots\times a}\\
   & b\mbox{ copies of }a
  \end{matrix} 
$$

For example,

$$
  \begin{matrix}
   4\uparrow 3= 4^3 = & \underbrace{4\times 4\times 4} & = & 64\\
   & 3\mbox{ copies of }4
  \end{matrix} 
 $$
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should be `\mathbin{\uparrow}` for correct spacing. If not used in the context of a delimiter, `\uparrow` behaves as a binary relation symbol. And, of course, `$$` should never be used in a LaTeX `document` environment.

Comment: @egreg  Thanks Point taken. Old habits die hard sometimes, and this was a quick hack. Always appreciate your comments and knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely, you're not loading `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
2^{\sum|f_{e}|} \qquad 2 \sum|f_{e}|
\]

\begin{center}% to show text mode
$2^{\sum|f_{e}|} \qquad 2 \sum|f_{e}|$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you uncomment `\usepackage{amsmath}` you'll get

[image]

The problem would however be the same if, together with `amsmath`, you also load `lmodern`. If this is the problem, load `fixcmex` that I wrote exactly to overcome this issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fixcmex}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
2^{\sum|f_{e}|} \qquad 2 \sum|f_{e}|
\]

\end{document}
```

The output is essentially the same as in the second picture.